# Method may produce NullPointerException warning despite a check

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

```
class Foo {
  @Nullable
  Object bar;

  boolean hasBar() {
    return bar != null;
  }

  @Nullable
  Object getBar() {
    return bar;
  }
}

someMethod(@NonNull Foo obj) {
  if(obj.hasBar()) {
    obj.getBar().toString(); <-- shows warning
  }
}
```

Any chances to get Android Studio to check the `hasBar` method to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [it's not possible at the moment](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000556184-Using-a-has-method-to-indicate-non-null).

Answer (score 1):

Alt+Enter, Right Click and choose any suppression of it you want.

[image]